# Android Studio doesn't align my code by attributes

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting

When I'm working in Android Studio and I want to make, for example, a new button. I type button and Android Studio gives me the correct line for inserting a button. When I press enter, Android Studio inserts it but it puts it in one line (see image)

[image]

But I want the code to be sort by attribute (see image)

[image]

The last one, I see in every tutorial, but mine doesn't do it automatically.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Now it takes so much time to align the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reformat your code with the below keyboard short cut.

```
Ctrl + Alt+ L
```

This short cut will format you complete file code. Whether that is XML or Java Code.

Hope this helps you.

**Alternatively**

You can do the same by going to your IDE Main Menu and selecting **Code > Reformat Code** or if you're only fixing alignment of text then **Code > Auto Indent Lines**.